# Golang Gorilla mux, best way to match against two url signatures

Tags: go, gorilla

Using gorilla mux, I currently have many URLs that are of the form:

domain.com/org/{subdomain}/{name}/pagename

such that the code looks like:

```
rtr.HandleFunc("/org/{subdomain}/{name}/promote", promoteView)
```

I'd like to also match against:

subdomain.domain.com/{name}/pagename

I know I can do something like

```
rtr.Host("{subdomain:[a-z]+}.domain.com").HandleFunc("/{name}/promote", promoteView)
```

to match on the subdomain. Is it possible to only have one HandleFunc() that will match both types of URLs, or do I need to have two HandleFunc()s, one for the first case and one for the subdomain.domain.com case?

Comment: What's wrong with handling them as 2 routes? They can both point to the same handler function. You have to declare both paths and the host somehow, so there's no real way to make this shorter.

Comment: I've got about 100 handlers and was hoping to avoid the code bloat/maintenance issues with having duplicate routes for each.

Comment: You have 2 routes here, so you need to define them somehow, and listing them separately probably makes maintenance easier. If combining the host+name pairs into a map of handlers (a la metakeule's answer) doesn't work for you either, then I think you need to make a better example for the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dispatcher like this you only have to add one line per router/handler.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

type key struct {
    subdomain, name string
}

type dispatcher map[key]http.Handler

func (d dispatcher) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    handler, ok := d[key{vars["subdomain"], vars["name"]}]

    if ok {
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return
    }
    http.NotFound(w, r)
}

func handleA(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(rw, "handleA serving")
}

func handleB(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(rw, "handleB serving")
}

var Dispatcher = dispatcher{
    key{"subA", "nameA"}: http.HandlerFunc(handleA),
    key{"subB", "nameB"}: http.HandlerFunc(handleB),
    // add your new routes here
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Handle("/org/{subdomain}/{name}/promote", Dispatcher)
    r.Host("{subdomain:[a-z]+}.domain.com").Path("/{name}/promote").Handler(Dispatcher)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

Comment: Sorry this may be a dumb question (but I learn more this way) - please can you explain how this Dispatcher approach reduces the code, as the above code has both `r.Handle` and `r.Host` calls from the OP.  It seems a different way to achieve the same, what have I missed?

Comment: It just makes it easy to add further handlers for a combination of domain and name. I guess that it the final goal. Say if you have 20 domain/name handlers just write the handler and add one new entry to the Dispatcher for each handler.

Comment: This doesn't change any of the routing, adding new pairs of handlers still takes almost exactly the same 2 lines. All you have done is added code to the original `promoteView` function, and made it an `http.Handler`.

Comment: @JimB Yes, so what? The whole thing only makes sense in the context of dispatching, so I've tried to provide a complete solution. Also solves comment of Mark "I've got about 100 handlers..." from above